# How to modify parser in PostgreSQL to handle new keyword and parse it

Tags: postgresql, parsing, yacc, postgresql-9.3

I am working on implementing Selectivity hints feature in PostgreSQL 9.3.4. I am working on this only for using it in my academic research. I have decided to give selectivity information per relation as part of query like shown below.

```
select * from lineitem, orders where l_extendedprice <=2400 and l_orderkey = o_orderkey selectivity(lineitem, 0.3) selectivity(orders, 0.7)
```

I tried separating the selectivity hint portion of the query before Postgres parses query. But it becomes very clumsy. I am thinking Postgres parser modification to handle this case could be complex that is why I did not get into Postgres grammar and parser. How should I take this selectivity hints separate from a normal query and populate in my data structures?

Comment: If you're implementing experimental features, wouldn't it make more sense to target the latest version, rather than patching a specific old release?

Comment: @IMSoP: isnt it the latest version barring the minor release 9.3.5?

Comment: Then why not use [the latest minor release](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? Also, it seems like the project mailing lists might be a good place for such a specific question. Start at http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/

Comment: [The Postgres community doesn't seem that thrilled about query hints at all](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/OptimizerHintsDiscussion)...

Comment: @fvu: I know that. That is why I have said in my post that this is only going to be used for my academic research.

Comment: @TheGame I was thinking more of checking out the latest source tree; [9.4 is in beta](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1533/) so there might be changes or fixes that would be advantageous.

Comment: You can't separate it easily. You really must modify the grammar. It's a yacc grammar, so there's lots of info out there about how to do so. (BTW, you should be working using `git` to manage your source tree, if you aren't already. Then you can `git rebase` onto a new release quite easily.)

Comment: @fvu They are not interested in hints of the nature "use this specific index, darn it".  Selectivity hints might be more favorably received, depending of course on the quality of the design and implementation.

Comment: Ignoring the hints-discussion, I do think that this "overruling the statistics" type of hint will fit reasonable into the planner's inner workings. Apart from the syntax-additions, some additions to the parse structures should be needed, plus some code changes at the places where the statistics are fetched or used. BTW: the "expect this fraction" estimate should refer to a RTE (or correlation name/ alias in the query), not to a table name. This will also avoid schema/namespace problems elegantly.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, the hints should refer to alias names used in the query rather than table name.